# Mysql - how to show value into same row from different column with condition

Tags: mysql

below is my code,

```
select DISTINCT C.session_id,C.status,C.uut_serial_num,D.error_code from 

(Select A.*

From uut_info A, session_info B

Where A.session_id=B.session_id

And A.uut_serial_num ="ACNW6676"
and A.status ="Fail" 
And B.test_spec<>'DBG'

Order By A.timestamp Desc

LIMIT 0,4) C left join subtest_info D 

on C.uut_serial_num = D.uut_serial_num
and C.session_id = D.session_id

order by C.timestamp Desc
```

Result:

```
session_id              status  uut_serial_num  error_code
7385122219fa35c37942511 Fail    ACNW6676    500004
7385122219fa35c37942511 Fail    ACNW6676    40555
7385122219fa35c37942511 Fail    ACNW6676    40187
7385122219fa35c37942511 Fail    ACNW6676    
412afc12a33601011721415 Fail    ACNW6676    
412afc12a33601011721415 Fail    ACNW6676    100001
9213232191116c821a59f86 Fail    ACNW6676    
9213232191116c821a59f86 Fail    ACNW6676    500005
11809c9a3382624993f5104 Fail    ACNW6676    40187
11809c9a3382624993f5104 Fail    ACNW6676    
11809c9a3382624993f5104 Fail    ACNW6676    40143
11809c9a3382624993f5104 Fail    ACNW6676    500005
```

but how to make/show if same session_id the error_code will mix in 1 row and remove empty like below, and same into tmp table?

```
    session_id          status  uut_serial_num  error_code
7385122219fa35c37942511 Fail    ACNW6676    500004,40555,40187
```

i tried with GROUP_CONCAT or If condition but still not able to get the result i want :-

```
select DISTINCT C.session_id,C.status,C.uut_serial_num,GROUP_CONCAT(D.error_code) from
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of distinct and use group by

```
Select your_columns, 
group_concat(d.error_code) from 
your_table group by session_id;
```

Comment: but this only will get 1 row,
only 1 session _id and all error code combine together.

what if i want only combine error code if the session id is same?

Comment: No, it will get distinct session ids.  Add the group by to your query as it sits and run it.

Comment: You will need to add a where error_code!='' as well if you only want populated values in your group_concat.

Comment: sorry this is my 1st time using mysql,
i using select DISTINCT C.session_id,C.status,C.uut_serial_num,group_concat(D.error_code) from ,
but the result come as below:-
7385122219fa35c37942511 Fail ACNW6676 40555,40187,500004,500004,500004,100001,500005,500005,40187,40143,40143,500005,500005,500005,40187,500005,500005

Comment: See my query above?  Get rid of the DISTINCT and add GROUP BY C.session_id after your table name.